# How to properly create an array of JSON objects in Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to create an array of JSON objects in typescript. And following is the approach I have used.

```
var queryMutations:any = _.uniq(_.map(mutationData.result,   
function(mutation:Mutation) {
    if (mutation && mutation.gene) {

        var item = {facet: "MUTATION", term: mutation.gene + " " + mutation.proteinChange}
        return item;
    }
    else {
        return {};
    }
}));

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(queryMutations);
```

is this the correct way to do it? Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks ok. I'd personally make a few layout style modifications and use backtick placeholder strings.

```
   var queryMutations:any = 
        _.uniq(
          _.map(
            mutationData.result,   
            function(mutation:Mutation) {
              if (mutation && mutation.gene) {
                return {facet: "MUTATION", 
                        term: `${mutation.gene} ${mutation.proteinChange}`
              } else {
                return {};
              }
            }
          )
        );

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(queryMutations);
```